# Русификация программы на Windows

Tags: windows

Есть небольшая программка "Laser Framework4", которая даётся в комплекте вместе с лазерным гравером.
Она частично на английском, частично на китайском с иероглифами...
[image: Laser Framework4]
Погуглив, нашёл несколько способов локализации программ, но, то о чём говориться в статьях, нет в данной программе.
Все скриншоты прикрепил к данной теме.
Программа даже не устанавливается, с гравером идёт флешка, на которой находится папка с данной программой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я ничего не понимаю в программа на Windows, просто хотелось локализовать программу и помочь людям в моей сфере, которые пользуются ею. У неё даже нет автора, просто поступает с поставщиком оборудования с Алика.

Comment: А при нажатии на English что происходит?

Comment: Ничего, изначально она на китайском, при нажатии на English частично переходит на английский, но только частично.

Comment: Хз, так сходу не понятно где локализуемые строки хранятся. Я бы попробовал загнать exe файл в дизассемблер и поискать строки в данных, может прямо в exe зашиты.

Comment: Я ещё помню времена, когда прямо в `exe` файле текстовые строки заменяли когда надо было текст перевести. Но нужно, чтобы хватило места под перевод. Иероглифы очень компактные, проблема с местом будет поверх них что-то на русском написать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну глобально эти времена никуда не ушли) Есть еще игры (например), где разработчик за 30 лет разработки не заморачивался с возможностью локализации, а игроки хотят хоть какой-то перевод, кривой-косой, но чтобы хоть что-то было понятно. Вот и приходится патчить захардкоженые строки, вешать хуки на методы строки, отлавливать текст на моменте рендеринга...